# Visual Studio doesn't work on my computer Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio

I have tried installing many versions of visual studio: 2015, 2013 and 2012.
I've successfully installed these versions but none of them works: When I start Visual Studio it opens and then shuts down by itself.

I searched a lot but didn't find a solution nor did I understand what the problem is.

Comment: Very vague, with this little information nobody can really help you. Please try to search for you problem.

Comment: i searched a lot but didn't understand what's the problem, when i open it, it shuts down by itself :/

Answer (score 0):

I run both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.  Windows 8 is a little quirky with how it handles application security.  It's possible you installed VS as a user without full privileges.  Try re-installing, but ensuring you are logged in as a user with administrator privileges.  Also, you might try running VS with the "Run As Administrator" option.